# Scraping href title using lxml and XPath

Tags: python, regex, xpath, lxml

```
from lxml import html
import requests

for i in range(44,530):      # Number of pages plus one 
    url = "http://postscapes.com/companies/r/{}".format(i)
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

contactemail = tree.xpath('//*[@id="rt-mainbody"]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/address/a')

print contactemail
```

I'm trying to scrape emails from 900 different pages on a company directory. The HTML code is relatively similar in every page. However, Contactemail returns **element values**. The XPath above is the href value for the code below. 
I'd like to extract **just the title** **contact@23-de-enero.com** from the href value via XPath,  but I don't know where quite to start. **I'd also like this to work for different pages, not just this href value / webpage.**

```
<a href="mailto:contact@23-de-enero.com">contact@23-de-enero.com</a>
```

I've looked into regex, and tried printing with `contactemail.textcontent()` but it doesn't work.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some possible ways to extract the same value i.e the email address, for example :

```
# get email address from inner text of the element :
print contactemail[0].text

# get email address from href attribute + substring-after() :
print contactemail[0].xpath('substring-after(@href, "mailto:")')
```

You can use list comprehension syntax if you may have multiple `a` elements in one `address` parent element :

```
print [link.text for link in contactemail]
```

Comment: Hey har07, thanks for the reply.
The first two return a index error, list is out of page.
The last one works, however it only returns None.

Comment: Seems like your XPath failed to locate the target element. What is the number in the url when the error was thrown? Try to simplify the XPath to : `//*[@id="rt-mainbody"]//address/a`

Comment: I simplified the xpath. It still returns None.

In regards to the number where the index error came to place, it begins from http://postscapes.com/companies/r/44 -> all the way to 530. 

I tried several other techniques 
   `for elt in contactemail:
            print(elt.text_content())`

but it starts returning weird values with the word email protection in it.